# PowerShell will not start

Tags: windows, powershell, .net-framework

I am getting this message when trying to run PowerShell

```
Version v4.0.30319 of the .NET Framework is not installed and it is required to
run version 3 of Windows PowerShell.
```

I have tried repairing *.NET Framework*, and I have tried
[reinstalling .NET](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642),
however the message persists. What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was caused by a missing registry key, this code took care of it

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"InstallRoot"="C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\"
```